# Java Security Manager: how to specify "No Permission"?

Tags: java, security

The Java Security Manager allows to specify the permissions of some piece of code by defining clauses like:

```
... 
grant codebase http://foo.bar.com/test.jar {
   permission java.io.FilePermission "${user.dir}/*", "read,write"; }; 
...
```

in a policy file (default: `<JRE_root>\lib\security`.
This grants code stemming from the given URL to read and write from/to the user's home directory (which is of course a no-no but that's another story).

But how do I define "NO permission", i.e. if that piece of code should NOT be allowed to read or write anywhere? I tried to specify:

```
...
  permission java.io.FilePermission "/-", ""; 
...
```

`"/-"` means the root directory and everything below it (i.e. everything) and the second argument `""` was meant to signal "". But when I specify this like above I get a "token error". Apparently `""` is not a valid "action". But how else does one then express "nothing" or "no permission" in these policy files?

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't add any permissions lines. Classes will typically be given permissions to read their own code and resources. (See the API docs for [java.io.FilePermission](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilePermission.html).)